# How to readrecords from Json Array

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, reference

I try to use Javascript Ext libraries and call a rest service which returns a json response. Its an array with one element and it doesnt work when i use DataReader(Ext.data.DataReader) "readRecords" operation to process the json data  and it returns null reference on the call back function. 
It would be good if you provide some help or suggestions to fix the issue.

I tried to pass the array as the argument in the reader and it doesnt help.

```
Ext.namespace("cityDetails");
var a = "http://" + "Url address to get cityDetails";
var e = new Ext.data.ScriptTagProxy({
  callbackParam: "callback",
  url: a
});
var f = {
  fields: [{
    name: "Id"
  }, {
    name: "city"
  }, {
    name: "postcode"
  }]
};
var d = new cityDetails.reader(f, {});
//call back function
var h = function(k, j, m) {
  try {
    // k returns null reference
    if (k != null) {
      alert("PostCode insider else::" + k.jsonObject.postcode)

    }

  }
} catch (l) {
  alert(l)
}
};
var i = this;
e.load({
  1: 1
}, d, h, i)

//readRecords from Data - Json Response an array of one objekt

Ext.extend(cityDetails.reader, Ext.data.DataReader, {
  readRecords: function(b) {
    this.jsonData = b;
    alert("Meta ::" + this.meta);
    //alert("Meta Root::"+this.meta.root);
    var a = false;
    return {
      success: a,
      jsonObject: this.getRoot(b),
      totalRecords: 1
    }
  },
  getRoot: function(d) {
    if (this.meta && this.meta.root) {
      var c = d;
      var a = this.meta.root.split(".");
      for (var b = 0; b < a.length; b++) {
        c = c[a[b]]
      }
      return c
    } else {
      alert("Value Of d in reader::" + d);
      if (d != null) {
        alert("Objects Of d in reader::" + d.jsonObject.postcode);
      }
      return d
    }
  }
})

//Initial call.

cityDetails.reader = function(a, b) {
  a = a || {};
  cityDetails.reader.superclass.constructor.call(this, a, b || a.fields)
};
```

Sample response from rest service shown below.

```
[{
  "Id": "121A",
  "postcode": "1000",
  "city": "ABBA"
}]
```

The call back function k should return the value of Json response. However it returns null.

Comment: Can you attach example on fiddle ? This code isn't working, problem is in `var d = new cityDetails.reader(f, {});` because cityDetails.reader not exists yet.

Comment: Yes.. Please see below.                                                            cityDetails.reader = function(a, b) {
  a = a || {};
  cityDetails.reader.superclass.constructor.call(this, a, b || a.fields)   
};

Comment: I tried to use JsonReader but it didnt help. Following is the sample.... cityDetails.reader= function(meta, recordType){
    meta = meta || {};
    Ext.data.JsonReader.superclass.constructor.call(this, meta, recordType || meta.fields);
};

Comment: Ext.extend(cityDetails.reader,Ext.data.DataReader,{
 readRecords:function(b){
  alert("Value Of d in reader::"+b);
  this.jsonData=b;
  var a=false;
   return{
    success:a,jsonObject:this.getRoot(b),totalRecords:1
   }
  },getRoot:function(d){
  if(this.meta&&this.meta.root){
   var c=d;
   var a=this.meta.root.split(".");
   for(var b=0;b<a.length;b++){
    c=c[a[b]]
   }return c
  }else{
   alert("Value Of d in reader::"+d);
//   if (d!=null) {
//    alert("Objects Of d in reader::"+d.jsonObject.postalcity);
//   }
   return d
  }
}});

Comment: The readRecords method is called when the json response has one object and something like below...  { "Id": "121A", "postcode": "1000",  "city": "ABBA"}   and however it returns "loadexception" when its an array of json response...... and looks the function inside the readRecords seem to be erroneous... Could someone please help what is wrong here